# Custom exception not thrown while using spring `@Retryable` annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

I am trying to implement retry attempts functionality while handling exception using `spring-retry`. I am using `@Retryable` as described in my code sample below. But I am facing a strange issue here.

When I use this annotation, it does retry for 3 times which is default, but it does not throw the custom exception, i.e. `MyGraphDBServiceException` which I have made for my application. Instead, it throws the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`. When I remove that annotation form the method, I get `MyGraphDBServiceException` as expected.

How can I ensure that `MyGraphDBServiceException` gets thrown even when I am using this annotation?

```
    @Override
    @Retryable(value = {MyGraphDBServiceException.class, MyGraphDBRedisServiceException.class}, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))
    public Long beginTransaction() {
        //TODO: provide custom exception handling here
        if (configs.isEmpty())
            throw new MyGraphDBServiceException(SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE_EXCEPTION);

        Long txnId = null;
        List<TransactionObject> txnList = new LinkedList<>();
        try {
            //should throw exception here which should be MyGraphDBServiceException
            txnId = txnList.get(0).getTransactionId();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String txnString = gson.toJson(txnList);
            redisServiceUtility.add(String.valueOf(txnId), txnString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO: provide custom exception handling here
            log.error("[Exception] Caught in redis: {}", e.getMessage());
            throw new MyGraphDBServiceException(SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        return txnId;
    }
```

just to be clear, I do get `MyGrpahDBServiceException` when I run the same code but without `@Retryable` annotation. So please don't think that my code should throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` rather than custom one.

Comment: You instantiate a list `txnList` with no items and you are trying the get (`txnList.get(0)`) the first item.

Comment: I know. That's what exception have to catch which is why `txnList.get(0)` throws an exception. Without using this annotation, it throws my exception as expected, but with this annotation, it doesn't throw this. Scenario is same in both cases.

Comment: How do you expect this line `txnId = txnList.get(0).getTransactionId();` should throw `MyGraphDBServiceException` and not `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` @CodeHunter?

Comment: @Deadpool because I am redirecting all  exceptions to throw my custom made exceptions. Thats how the normal thing is working btw. It is just with annotation it doesn't work.

Comment: just to be clear, I do get `MyGrpahDBServiceException` when I run the same code but without `@Retryable` annotation. So please don't think that my code should throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` rather than custom one.

Comment: No actually what does it throws after exhausting retry @CodeHunter

Comment: after exhausting retries only it throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Comment: i will suggest to debug and print this `configs` everytime @CodeHunter